# Inequality replacement of numbers

Tags: inequality

I'm looking for a contradiction or a proof.

Suppose we have the following inequality:

> $a\cdot j \leq b \cdot h$

Where $a,b,j,h \in \mathbb{N}$.

We now replace $a$ with $a_{1}$ and $b$ with $b_{1}$, where $a_{1}, b_{1} \in \mathbb{N}$. We also have the following situation:

1. $a_{1}\leq a$
2. $b_{1}\leq b$
3. $b-b_{1}\leq a-a_{1}$

Can we then deduce that $a_{1}\cdot j \leq b_{1} \cdot h$ is true?

**For instance:**

$4\cdot 6 \leq 7 \cdot 5$

In this case $a = 4, b=7$.
We now replace $a$ with $a_{1} = 3$ so $a - a_{1} = 1$. Since $b-b_{1}\leq a-a_{1} = 1$ we have $b_{1}\in\lbrace 6,7 \rbrace$.
In both cases:

1. $3\cdot 6 \leq 7 \cdot 5$
2. $3\cdot 6 \leq 6 \cdot 5$

The inequality with the replacements of $a,b$ is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot, since it is false in general: let $j=1,h=5,a=10,b=2$, so that
$$
a\cdot j=10\cdot 1=10 \leq 10=2\cdot 5=b\cdot h
$$
then let $a_1=9,b_1=1$, thus

1. $a_1=9\leq 10=a$
2. $b_1=1\leq 2=b$
3. $b-b_1=2-1=1\leq 1=10-9=a-a_1$

and
$$
a_1\cdot j =9\cdot 1=9 \geq 5=1\cdot 5=b_1\cdot h
$$

Answer (score 0):

So, will this work?

Initially:
$$b-b_{1}\leq a-a_{1}.$$
Multiply by $h$:
$$b \ h-b_{1} h\leq a \ h-a_{1} h.$$
Use the first inequality:
$$a\ j - b_1 h\leq b\ h-b_{1} h\leq a \ h-a_{1} h$$
$$a\ j - b_1 h\leq a \ h-a_{1} h.$$
Rearrange the terms:
$$a \ (j-h)+a_1 h \leq b_1 h.$$
Use equation $(1)$:
$$a_1(j-h)+a_1 h\leq a \ (j-h)+a_1 h \leq b_1 h.$$
And get:
$$a_1j\leq b_1 h$$
Well, but you'll need $(j-h)\geq 0$.

Comment: Also, you cannot guarantee that $aj-b_1h\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: @A.P. And? What's the problem with it? Nor you can with $a \ h-a_{1} h$

Comment: Well, the OP was asking for an inequality in $\Bbb N$. Sure, you could look at it immersing $\Bbb N$ in $\Bbb Z$ and coming back, but you should say so.